# Showing elements based on data attr in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a nav (`.navigation`) which contains `li`'s that have a `data-panel` assigned to them.

This is how I'm looking for it to work:

1. By default, the `#screenOne` panel is active (because it has the `.active` class)
2. User then clicks a `.navigation__li`, then it will get that elements `data-panel` attr and add the `selected` class to that `li` element
3. It will then also add the `active` class to the `.panel` that has the matching ID as the `li` the user clicks on.

With my current implementation, I'm running into `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAttribute')` errors.

### Here is my current approach:

`src/components/Navigation`

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import changePanel from '../../utils/helpers';

class Navigation extends React.Component{

  render(){

    return(

      <div className="navigation">
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <nav className="navigation__nav">
                <Container>
                  <Row className="justify-content-center">
                    <Col>

                      <ul className="navigation__ul reset-list d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <li className="navigation__li selected" data-panel="screenOne" onClick={ changePanel }>Panel 1</li>
                        <li className="navigation__li" data-panel="screenTwo" onClick={ changePanel }>Panel 2</li>
                      </ul>

                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </Container>
              </nav>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>

    )
  }

}

export default Navigation;
```

`src/components/Screen`

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

function Screen(props) {

  const sectionID = props.id;
  const tag = props.tag;
  const header = props.header;

  return(

    <div className="panel active" id={sectionID}>
      <Container>
        <Row className="justify-content-center align-items-center">

          <Col xs={12} md={6}>
            <div className="panel__left fadeIn">
              <h1 className="panel__left-title">
                <span className="d-block">{tag}</span>
                <span className="d-block">{header}</span>
              </h1>
            </div>
          </Col>

        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>

  )

}

export default Screen;
```

`src/utils/helpers`

```js
const changePanel = function() {

  // get data-panel attr from .navigation
  let panelID = this.getAttribute("data-panel");

  // remove active state from all .panel's
  let allPanels = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.panel'));
  for (let panel of allPanels) {
    panel.classList.remove('active');
  }

  // make the matching panel ID active
  document.querySelector("#"+ panelID).classList.add("active");

  // make the clicked nav item active
  let navItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.nagivation__li'));
  for (let navItem of navItems) {
    navItem.classList.remove('selected');
  }

  this.addClass("selected");

  // debugging
  console.log(panelID);

}

export default changePanel;
```

`src/pages/Homepage`

```js
import React from "react";
import Screen from "../components/Screen/Screen";
import Navigation from "../components/Navigation/Navigation";

class Homepage extends React.Component {

  render(){

    return (
      <section id="project">
        <Screen id="screenOne" tag="Panel 1" header="Screen 1"/>
        <Screen id="screenTwo" tag="Panel 2" header="Screen 2"/>
        <Navigation />
      </section>
    );

  }

}

export default Homepage;
```

Comment: Instead of fixing this problem, I suggest you just do this in a simpler, more React way.  Use functional components (classes are relics) and employ a `useState` to determine which component to show.  Also, your child components are similar enough that you should consider using just one component and passing it the necessary props.

Comment: @jmargolisvt - Hi, what do you mean by “classes are relics”? I’m new to React and learning from a WesBos course (https://reactforbeginners.com/) in which classes are being used? I have also reworked my components to use `props` - have edited question to showcase.

Comment: If you see a class component in production, you can be assured it's a relic from before the introduction of hooks to React.  Hooks were introduced because class components are no fun to work with.  Classes are like the cursive handwriting of React: maybe good to know about, but rarely used or seen in the wild these days.